# Hot update a service that start by upstart or systemd

Tags: auto-update, systemd, upstart

A service start by Upstart or systemd and I want hot update it. After update, the new service process is running and then kill the old service process that start by upstart or systemd. A at last, the new process can be monitored by the upstart or systemd as the old process.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your service does. I am answering for the easy case, a network service with short-lived connections, such as an HTTP server.

1. Have systemd own the socket. Search for "systemd socket activation" ([stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=systemd+socket+activation)). I describe how to do it in Go here: https://www.darkcoding.net/software/systemd-socket-activation-in-go/
2. While the service is running, replace the binary on disk with the new one.
3. `systemctl restart <myservice>`

In practice there will often also be some state in your service you will need to persist on shutdown, and load on startup.

The service shutting down might need to wait a brief amount of time until all it's requests complete.

For the more difficult case with many long-lived TCP connections (such as an XMPP server), it's no longer about systemd, you have to have your old and new processes co-ordinate to pass the sockets from one to another. I describe it in [Online upgrades in Go](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/online-upgrades-in-go/), but it's a lot more work.